# Query in a loop which is executed only once Java

Tags: java, sql, swing, for-loop, jdbc

I am currently working on a Java project (on NetBeans) and I am struggling with a problem.

In fact, I have a `jTable` which contains several elements, which element has a `jCheckBox` in the second column and I would like to make a query to add the selected element (selected by the `jCheckBox` of course) in a table.

I can get the data that I want to add, but my query works only once. I have already check my loop but I don't where the problem comes from.

I let you see the code :

```
try {
    // Getting id of the selected value in the jComboBox
    String idParcours = oParcoursDAO.findIdParcours(jComboBoxParcours.getSelectedItem().toString());
    int id = Integer.parseInt(idParcours);

    // for each value in the jTable
    for(int i=0; i <jTable2.getRowCount(); i++){

        boolean isChecked = (Boolean)jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1);
        String nomPoi = (String)jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0);     
            // if the value is selected
            if(isChecked){
                String IDPoi = oParcoursDAO.findIdPoi(nomPoi);
                int idpoi = Integer.parseInt(IDPoi);

                System.out.println("idpoi "+idpoi); // It works I saw as idpoi as I have choose
                System.out.println("id "+id) // It works too

                oParcoursDAO.addPoi(idpoi,id);   // it works only once             
             }
        }               
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ModificationParcoursJInternalFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

This is my statement

```
public void addPoi(int idPoi,int idParcours) throws SQLException{

    String query = "INSERT INTO TB_POI_PARCOURS (id_poi,id_parcours) VALUES (?,?) ";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1,idPoi);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2,idParcours);  
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    preparedStatement.close();
}
```

Comment: i saw that you haven't an error in your code , so try to debug you code and add  print statement after each line to check where is the problem

Comment: I have already tried this, and when I print the query it was printed as many times as expected so I really don't understand why there is only one add in my database ..

Comment: so i guess that you have a problem in you database , so can you post your db statements  ?

Comment: Can't it be you marked id_poi as UNIQUE in your TB_POI_PARCOURS table?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i've checked @user3008950

Answer (score 2):

Why are you running one query per line? You can execute all of them in a single SQL using batch queries. It will require you to change the code but it will make it more efficient:

```
public void addPoi(Map<integer,Integer> poiMap) throws SQLException{

    String query = "INSERT INTO TB_POI_PARCOURS (id_poi,id_parcours) VALUES (?,?) ";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    for(Integer idPoi:poiMap.keySet()) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,idPoi);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2,poiMap.get(idPoi));  
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
    }
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    preparedStatement.close();
}
```

Of course the original method has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know batch queries ! I am beginner and I am not familiar with Map, can you tell me how to use it?

Comment: Convert your original method to save the poiId and parcoursId into a Hashmap, and then call addPoi() once, with the map. The code for getPoi() is given.